# Django Template Tags - Return multiple values or object

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a Django (1.5) template tag that I am using in a partial view to render some random content. The tag makes a query for a single record. I have no problem returning a single item but when trying to send back the full object for use or multiple items I am having trouble.

**Here is my tag**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('_footer.html')
def get_random_testimonial():
    # Grab random record
    record = Testimonials.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    return record.text
```

I would like to be able to return both record.text and record.id to the template tag

**To render the tag I have this in my _footer.html view**

```
{% load current_tags %}
{% get_random_testimonial %}
```

Is there a way I can just return the record object and be able to get all of the values of that object with something like:

```
 {% get_random_testimonial.text %}
 {% get_random_testimonial.id %}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This doesn't make sense as an inclusion tag. Especially as you seem to be using it in the same template as you have told it to render.

What you need is an [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags):

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_random_testimonial():
    return Testimonials.objects.order_by('?')[0]
```

Then you can do:

```
{% get_random_testimonial as my_testimonial %}
{{ my_testimonial.text }}
{{ my_testimonial.id }}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, new to template tags and was a bit confused on the difference between the 2 and when each should be used.

Comment: Look like assignment_tag does not exist anymore

Comment: Well, this answer is six years old. You can replace it with `simple_tag`, which now supports exactly the same assignment syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer

In case you want to return multiple native objects you can do this

```py
@register.simple_tag
def get_random_values(arg1, arg2):
    # some logics...
    return value1, value2, value3
```

Then in your templates you can get them as

```html
{% get_random_values arg1 arg2 as random_values %}
<p>{{ random_values.0 }}</p> // to get value1
<p>{{ random_values.1 }}</p> // to get value2
<p>{{ random_values.2 }}</p> // to get value3
```

Note:
0, 1 and 2 are termed as indexes, so based on the position of the value you can access it via its index